# 'y' of 'Equal' Op has type int32 that does not match type int64 of argument 'x'

Tags: python, tensorflow

**I get this error when I try to test the NN model, can you please help me out**
I know the error is about the dtype, but I have no idea how to solve it.

```
# Test model
correct_prediction = tf.equal(prediction, y_placeholder)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X_placeholder: X_test, y_placeholder: y_test}))
```

**And the error message is:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16648\358347498.py in <module>
      1 # Test model
----> 2 correct_prediction = tf.equal(prediction, y_placeholder)
      3 accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.int32))
      4 print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X_placeholder: X_test, y_placeholder: y_test}))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151     except Exception as e:
    152       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154     finally:
    155       del filtered_tb

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in _ExtractInputsAndAttrs(op_type_name, op_def, allowed_list_attr_map, keywords, default_type_attr_map, attrs, inputs, input_types)
    586                 inferred_from[k] = "Default in OpDef"
    587 
--> 588           raise TypeError(
    589               f"{prefix} type "
    590               f"{dtypes.as_dtype(attrs[input_arg.type_attr]).name} of "

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Equal' Op has type int32 that does not match type int64 of argument 'x'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the types of the 'x' and 'y' inputs to the tf.equal function don't match. In your case, 'x' (prediction) has type int64 and 'y' (y_placeholder) has type int32.

You can use tf.cast to change the type of one of the inputs.

I am editing my code for both versions of tf:

**Tf1**

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(prediction, tf.cast(y_placeholder, tf.int64)) 
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print("Accuracy:", sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X_placeholder: X_test, y_placeholder: y_test}))
```

**Tf2**

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(prediction, tf.cast(y_placeholder, tf.int64)) 
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print("Accuracy:", accuracy.numpy())
```

Comment: I get this error now.
ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)

Comment: Check your tensorflow version. Are you using tf1 or tf2?

Comment: I edited my code for both versions